# Why is it discouraged to directly instantiate the Dialog class?

Tags: android, android-dialog

I want to show a dialog when the user clicks on an option menu inside an Activity. I first wanted to do this using the Dialog class. The code is something similar to the one below.

```
final Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
d.setContentView(R.layout.customDialog);
d.setTitle("Sample title");

data = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.data);
button = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.aButton);
d.show();

button.setOnClickListner(new View.OnClickListner() { 
    // grab data from edittext and save it to some var 

    d.dismiss();
});
```

Something like that. The dev guide suggests I not instantiate directly a Dialog class. Is there something particularly bad about this approach ?

Answer (score 0):

The android dev guide adds a lot of extra info to help developers avoid tasks which take up a lot of processing time. Instantiating a Dialog class directly probably takes up a lot more processing time.

Answer (score 0):

The system keeps a cache of dialogs, so you don't have to manage it yourself. Each dialog is created only once and stored somewhere so it can be reused later. That's because creating a dialog is computationally expensive, I guess. The system gives you the hooks to create the dialog the first time it's needed and to prepare it just before showing